# Run fixed effect and logit regression on a national survey that need to be "weighted" in R?

Tags: r, logistic, fixed-effects-model, probit, survey-weights

I am a beginner user of R. I am using a national survey to test what variables influence the participation in complementary pensions (the participation in complementary pension is voluntary in my country).

Since the dependent variable is a dummy (1 if the person participate and 0 otherwise) I want to run a logit or probit regression; moreover I want to run a fixed effect regression since I subset the survey in order to have only the individuals interviewed more than one time.

The data frame is composed by several social and economical variables and it also contain a variable "weight" which is the survey weight (they are weighting coefficients to adjust the results of the sample to the national data).

```
 family pers sex income pension
1     10    1   F  10000       1
2     20    1   F  20000       1
3     20    2   M  40000       0
4     30    1   M  25000       0
5     30    2   F  50000       0
6     40    1   M  60000       1
```

pers is the component of the family and pension takes 1 if the person participate to complementary pension (it is a simplification of the original survey, which contains more variables and observation (around 22k observations)).

I know how to use the plm and glm functions for a fixed effect or logit regression; in this case I don't know what to do since I need to take account of the survey weights.

I used the `svydesign` function to "weight" the data frame:

```
df1 <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=df, weights=~dfweight)
```

I used ids=~1 because there isn't a "cluster" variable in the survey (I know that the towns are ramdomly selected and then individuals are ramdomly selected, but there isn't a variable that indicate the stratification).

At this point I am lost: I don't know if it is right to use the survey package and then what function use to run the regression, or there is a way to use the plm or glm functions taking account of the weights.

I tried so hard to search a solution on the website but if you could give me an answer I'd be glad.

Comment: Ideally, `id` would specify the towns. If you use `id=~1` when it's actually cluster sampled the standard errors will tend to be wrong (usually, but not always, underestimated).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to use sample weights with `glm`. I don't know about `plm`, but it seems to me that it's mostly about analyzing panel data (repeated cross-sectional surveys with the same cohort).

You can use the `svyglm()`function of the survey package:

```
df1 <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=df, weights=~dfweight)
model1 <- svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2, design = df1, data=df, family=quasibinomial)
```

The quasibinomial is used instead of the bionomial distribution to account for that your dependent variables will be different from 0 and 1 because of the weighting.

Comment: Actually, the quasibinomial() function is used with svyglm() only to suppress an annoying warning that you get with binomial(). The results are identical.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thanks!